# What/Where is the android ActionBar?

Tags: android

I've never really handled an android device before. I've read most of the discussion on here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

From what I gather if I'm using a Holo theme and that my target is at least API level 11 I should have an action bar within my app.

How exactly do I open it up with the keyboard? My emulator has a custom size(8" tablet) and I don't know how to see the action bar :

[image]

As you see on the screen I have no idea where this bar is supposed to be at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its that bar at the top with the app title in it!

Comment: Ok, so I suppose I'm the one that has to add actions and buttons right?

Answer (score 1):

As most of us android developer - I assume - still want to support Froyo, many of us use

[actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

which brings Action Bar down to API 2.x 
- from my experience with it so far it is an awesome lib.

Just a hint for the case you start liking the Action Bar ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into it once I meddle with this one.